# É possível (e desejável) reduzir o requisito para comentar?

Tags: debate, status-recusado, comentários, privilégios

Um dos "problemas" mais comuns que vejo envolvendo usuários novos é que, na falta de reputação suficiente para comentar, eles adicionam respostas que "não são respostas". Normalmente são precedidas de um *disclaimer* tipo "não tenho privilégio de comentar, então estou postando como resposta" - o que demonstra claramente que estão cientes das regras mas optaram por violá-las. Pessoalmente, acho até acertada a decisão, pois em geral os comentários-resposta acrescentam algo de útil, e são tentativas genuínas de ajudar ao OP. E me parece que a comunidade concorda em ser leniente nesse caso, pelos comentários que vejo nesse tipo de resposta.

Não seria o caso então de "relaxar" o requisito para se deixar comentários? Não creio que devíamos baixá-lo para zero (pois isso abriria a porta para spam e outros vandalismos), mas talvez colocá-lo no mesmo nível de "remover as restrições de usuário novo". Imagino que isso esteja dentro das capacidades da engine do site (parametrizar os requisitos de reputação), mas não tenho certeza...

Seria possível fazer esse ajuste? E caso positivo, seria desejável? Isso com certeza ia reduzir o número de posts desse tipo na fila de análise, bem como dar menos trabalho aos moderadores (que são os únicos que podem converter resposta em comentário). Ou haveria algum viés nisso que não estou enxergando?

Comment: Eu acho uma proposta bastante interessante. Eu mesmo apesar de não perguntar e responder frequentemente abro o site quase todos os dias para ver o que há de novo. E a falta de privilégio para comentar acaba sendo um grande empecilho para aqueles que não tem uma boa comunidade na sua área aqui. Eu mesmo fui ganhar privilégios para comentar apenas hoje, e devo estar aqui quase todos os dias a pelo menos um mês.

Comment: Alguém sabe se tem algum outro site do Stackexchange exige menos de 50 pontos para comentar? Acho que seria bom poder aproveitar discussões existentes sobre os privilégios ao inv';es de reinventar a roda.

Answer (score 20):

Essa é uma situação em que a SE fica entre a cruz e a espada. O principal argumento contra a diminuição, ou até a extinção, do requisito para comentar é que o que nós queremos dos comentários aqui é bem diferente do que os outros sites querem.

Mais do que os conceitos de *perguntar* e *responder*, entender para que serve um comentário no site demora mais tempo. Em outros lugares o campo de comentário normalmente serve como "posta aí o que você quiser", e esse não é o caso aqui no Stack Exchange. Por isso que eles só são liberados para pessoas que já demonstraram que estão dispostas a participar e ajudar o site.

O receio é que ao liberar comentários, vai haver uma chuva de "Primeiro!", "(y)/+1/Like/Gostei/etc...", "Eu também!", "Seu burro!" e outras coisas charmosas assim, que podem se tornar incontroláveis. O trabalho de criar um comentário ruim é infinitamente menor que o de limpá-lo.

**Particularmente** não é o que eu vejo no nosso site, mas há uma gigantesca falha nessa análise: Se eu não vejo comentários ruins o tempo todo, pode ser *justamente* porque o sistema funciona. Eu vejo sim diversas pessoas que gostariam de ter feito comentários que eram muito úteis, e que acabam criando respostas pra contornar a restrição... Plenamente conscientes de que estão usando a ferramenta errada pra isso, mas sem uma alternativa viável.

Vendo isso, eu conversei essa semana sobre o motivo dessa regra, e se já havia sido debatido alterá-la... E no final das contas é uma das coisas que talvez vá sim, um dia ser revista, mas que por enquanto vai permanecer do jeito que está.

Eu realmente entendo que é um saco pra quem quer adicionar um bom comentário e não pode, mas mover um resposta para um comentário esporadicamente é muito mais simples que ter que lidar com dezenas de comentários ruins.

Comment: É verdade, a quantidade de lixo que não entra no sistema por conta dessa limitação deve ser *muito* grande..!

Comment: @brasofilo Pois é. Não temos como saber, mas também não queremos experimentar e descobrir :D

Comment: Seria interessante permanecer com a restrição, porém de uma forma diferente, o usuário postar um comentário e ficar em uma fila de análise, mas claro, apenas para quem tem a reputação menor que a exigida para comentar. Seria como um usuário com pontuação abaixo de 1000 fazer uma edição.

Answer (score 12):

Diversos fóruns os quais participei ao longo da minha jornada como programador sofreram e ainda sofrem com a inexperiência e a preguiça de pessoas que acham que são programadores.

O modelo administrativo do Stack Overflow, no entanto, permite gerir tanto seu conteúdo quanto seus usuários com punhos de ferro e minimizar, pra não dizer extinguir, esse tipo de problema não por impor diretrizes através de suas metas restritivas mas sim por separar o joio do trigo com elas.

Mesmo recém chegado, tenho bagagem de anos e confesso que achei frustrante não poder puxar a orelha de alguém por causa dessas permissões. Mas conhecendo o modelo como conheço, fiquei feliz por não conseguir fazê-lo.

Bastou expor parte do meu conhecimento que o reconhecimento veio com menos de 10 postagens. Isso é qualidade!

Se houver uma postagem com esse *disclaimer* (adorei a colocação) explícito ou não, cabe aos usuários experientes e com mais permissões ainda "castigarem" o autor negativando-o, sinalizando sua resposta à moderação (supondo que estes assim sejam chamados por aqui) e, quem sabe, este ter sua postagem excluída.

Comment: Já que essa resposta apareceu recentemente como origem de uma medalhinha... eu digo "ah! se eu soubesse o quanto o "modelo" da Stack Exchange — não a versão brasileira, claro — decaiu e se perverteu com os anos..."

Answer (score 10):

Você pode sempre comentar em perguntas e respostas que você mesmo tenha feito.

Quanto a restrição a comentários, não é a única restrição para novos usuários. A [ajuda da matriz](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) menciona todas as restrições:

- Postar mais de duas URL's em qualquer lugar (pergunta, resposta, comentário ou perfil);
- Responder em perguntas protegidas;
- Postar várias perguntas ou respostas em um curto espaço de tempo.

Se for necessário justificativa, esses são os motivos:

> **Why are restrictions placed on new users?**
>
> Because we allow participation from anonymous internet users, we must take some precautions to ensure that the rare malicious or spammy anonymous user doesn't ruin the experience for everyone else.
>
> We're sorry that we have to sandbox new users, but the first few upvotes on your questions or answers will quickly elevate you out of it!

Numa tradução livre (e curta e grossa): pra evitar spam.

Sinceramente, **não é difícil conseguir 50 pontos**. Algumas boas perguntas ou respostas e você "está dentro". É como um ritual de iniciação. É também uma boa forma de garantir que quem venha a participar está alinhado com a filosofia do site. Você não vai ganhar esse privilégio, por exemplo, se tudo que você perguntar estiver fora dos temas do *SOePT*. Ou se suas respostas não contribuírem em nada.

E se você tem uma determinada pontuação em qualquer site do *Stack Exchange* (duzentos pontos, acredito), então você já tem automaticamente cento e um pontos em qualquer site da rede no qual nunca tenha participado. Caso o interessado em comentar participe de outros sites, como o *Server Fault*, *Code Review* etc., logo logo estará a comentar por aqui também.

**Um adendo:** os colegas me chamaram a atenção ao fato de que aqui no *SOePT*, o limite que separa os novatos do "pessoal da casa" é 50 pontos. <strike>Isso é cinco vezes mais do que no *Stack Overflow*</strike> ([é o mesmo limite no Stack original](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)). Eu acho que 10 pontos seria o ideal. Se for possível reduzir o limite de 50 para 10, sou a favor de que seja feito. Realmente o limite de 50 pontos requer um pouco mais de esforço do que 10. Porém ainda mantenho minha afirmação de que alcançar 50 pontos não é difícil. Muitos de nós fizemos muito mais que isso em pouquíssimo tempo - eu mesmo fiz 50 pontos apenas no meu segundo dia aqui.

Comment: São necessários 50 pontos para comentar em qualquer post, não 10.

Comment: @Renan Se fossem 10 pontos realmente estaria ótimo. Mas são 50 pontos. Acredito que 10 pontos era na época do beta fechado.

Comment: "Isso é cinco vezes mais do que no Stack Overflow" Na verdade é igual: remover as restrições de usuário novo é `10`, comentar em todos os lugares é `50`. Não me lembro como era no beta fechado. De todo modo, concordo com suas colocações.

Comment: Também concordo com as colocações e não acho que os limites devam ser alterados. Mas será que nesses casos de resposta-comentário poderíamos, além de apresentar as regras, indicar aos usuários que façam uma *sugestão de edição*? A sugestão terá de ser aprovada por outros com mais reputação, mas pode eliminar a frustração de não poder ajudar até ter reputação suficiente.

Comment: @LuizVieira acredito que há um limite mínimo de reputação para sugerir edições, não?

Comment: @Renan Creio que para fazer edições diretamente (isto é, sem a necessidade de que sejam aprovadas) o mínimo é 2 mil pontos. Mas para sugerir não parece haver mínimo. Até dei uma olhada na lista de privilégios e não há indicação de restrição na sugestão de edições: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Esse **adendo** não faz sentido nenhum... logo antes você destaca que "não é difícil conseguir 50 pontos" para enseguida dizer que "50 pontos é mais intimidante"... (?) . . . . Além disso, é factualmente incorreto, sempre foi 50 pontos em qualquer site.

Comment: @brasofilo valeu pelo toque :) editei para fazer mais sentido e corrigir a afirmação do limite diferente.

Comment: Discordo com a redução para 10 pontos, creio que 50 pontos é o suficiente.