# Agora reputação 1 pode comentar, ou é bug?

Tags: suporte, bug, status-intencional

User: [123107](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/123107)

Pergunta: [323973](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/323973/apagar-dados-mysql)

Comentário: [656057_323973](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/323973/apagar-dados-mysql?noredirect=1#comment656057_323973)

[image: print]

Comment: no seu próprio post, pode

Comment: Eu converti a 'resposta' em comentário.

Comment: Tem uma discussão legal em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/817/70

Comment: @Bacco Não sabia disso! Mas não foi o caso também! rs... rray Também não sabia que podiam fazer isso! Entendidos! ✌️

Comment: @RobertodeCampos É da pergunta. Tem link comentário? Porque só conheço o up e sinalizar.

Comment: Clica na data que vc captura o link igual um pokemon!11

Comment: @rbz quando vc tiver 10000 pontos vai poder ver coisas assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhx3b.png

Comment: @rray bota como resposta oficial, acho que esse assunto vai surgir mais vezes (se é que nao tem já postado)

Comment: @rray Copiado! Aprendido!

Comment: @Bacco Caraca... 10.000 vai uns anos aí! Bacana!

Comment: Um outro caso que poderia ser possível, mas não neste, a pessoa perdeu 50 pontos depois que comentou :D

Comment: @Maniero Pensei nisso! kkk Mas olhei o perfil dele, não tinha movimento! hahaha

Comment: @Maniero ou foi pro cantinho da disciplina pra acalmar :p

Comment: @Articuno tem isso tb :)

Comment: @Articuno Agora que você disse isso me veio em mente um usuário que eu reparei uma vez que tinha movimentação na reputação, mas estava como 1 se não me engano. Existe um "bloqueio temporário"?

Comment: @rbz sim, se o usuario apresentar um comportamento que viole o codigo de conduta, ou for pego manipulando votos ou coisas desse tipo, pode ser suspenso de interagir no site temporariamente, ai a punicao depende do q ele fez e do historico comportamental dele.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O usuário colocou os questionamentos para o OP no espaço para as respostas, então converti a resposta em comentário quem tem 10 mil de reputação consegue ver a exclusão.

O requisito para criar comentários em outras postagem que não seja a sua continua sendo os 50 pontos.

Conforme o link/imagem fornecido pelo Bacco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]