# O que vocês acham de zerar a pontuação de todos os usuários e começar tudo do zero?

Tags: debate

Já que o intuito no Stackoverflow não é ganhar fama e nem reputação com a pontuação obtida. Mas sim ajudar ao próximo para que a área de T.I possa ser uma comunidade melhor.

O que você acham de zerar a pontuação de todos os usuário e deixar todo mundo com 0 pontos ? Zerar a plataforma. Vida nova ao site e aos usuários.

Sei que isso é uma questão meio que surreal e fantasiosa. Levem para o lado da fantasia mesmo e expliquem os impactos que vocês vêem acontecendo, se uma coisa desse viesse a ocorrer.

> "O que são os pontos pra vcs ? Reputação ? Reconhecimento ? Status ?
> Ganham alguma coisa material através desses pontos ? O real propósito
> aqui não é ajudar ao próximo para que ele se torne um profissional
> melhor ? Se for isso, que importância os pontos tem ? Uma pessoa com
> 100 pontos pode ajudar tanto quanto uma de 100k. Todos os anos que
> essa pessoa ajudou continuaria lá, registrados nas memórias de quem
> foi ajudado e de quem ajudou. Isso já não bastaria ? Ou o status e
> posição propiciados pela 'reputação' tem uma importância relevante pra
> vocês ?"

Observo muito as pessoas modificando as "próprias perguntas e respostas antigas" para ela subir para a página principal e fico na dúvida:

> "Isso é feito para ajudar as pessoas, que estão em procurando ajuda, verem
> esses tópicos que possam ser úteis para elas ou é feito somente para
> que perguntas e respostas antigas (que estavam esquecidas) apareçam na
> página principal e sejam visualizadas para angariarem mais votos,
> fazendo com que essa pessoa responsável por elas ganhem mais pontos
> consequentemente ? A intenção nesse caso é ajudar ou ganhar pontos ? Se não valessem pontos, a vontade de ajudar, moderar o site e modificar perguntas e respostas antigas para subirem no Feed e 'ajudar os usuários' seria o mesmo ?"

**OBS:** Nessa minha ideia, a moderação continuaria!

Foi só uma curiosidade que passou na minha cabeça e queria compartilhar essa doideira com vocês.

Comment: A conversa ficou muito extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113083/discussion-on-question-by-gato-de-schrodinger-o-que-voces-acham-de-zerar-a-pontu) - Quem quiser se inteirar, ler e/ou interagir pode clicar no link fornecido.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *ajudar ao próximo para que a área de T.I possa ser uma comunidade melhor*

Na verdade não é *bem* assim. A ideia do site (explicada [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/112052), [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/112052) e em muitos outros *posts* do meta) é criar um repositório de conhecimento, usando o formato de perguntas específicas sobre programação + respostas focadas em resolver este problema específico.

Por isso existe um [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) que define os tipos de perguntas que são aceitos aqui. Por exemplo, se a pessoa só coloca um enunciado do exercício e não coloca o código que tentou (ou põe o código mas não explica o problema), ela só quer que façamos todo o trabalho para ela, e [isso nós não fazemos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/112052) (claro que tem gente que faz, mas esses estão errados). **Se** a ideia fosse "ajudar o próximo", então esse tipo de pergunta seria aceita, não? Mas a ideia é ter um repositório de conhecimento com perguntas que sejam úteis não apenas para quem perguntou, mas para qualquer visitante futuro que tenha o mesmo problema (e enunciados de faculdade são *no máximo* úteis para quem está fazendo aquele curso, e cai mais na categoria *helpdesk*, que também não é a ideia do site).

A diferença é sutil: claro que as boas respostas ajudam as pessoas, mas o objetivo principal é gerar o repositório de conhecimento, com informações de qualidade que sirvam de referência para todos (por isso não aceitamos qualquer gambiarra, e respostas que só dão o código pronto mas não explicam nada [também são consideradas ruins](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/112052)). O fato de ajudar as pessoas é secundário, praticamente uma consequência de se criar tal repositório.

Então a pergunta já parte de uma premissa errada.

---

## Tá, mas e os pontos?

Do ponto de vista prático, podemos dizer que os pontos não servem para nada. Afinal, são apenas pontos imaginários na Internet. Alguns podem até achar que dá algum *status*, sei lá. E claro que o *gamification* pode gerar distorções, gente que tenta "manipular" o sistema para ganhar mais pontos. Assim como tem gente que se motiva a participar mais para ter uma pontuação alta. Mas também tem quem não liga pra isso. Enfim, qualquer sistema *gamificado* vai ter esses problemas.

A pontuação *no máximo* indica que a pessoa participou bastante, mas não é o suficiente para indicar como foi essa participação. Se você participar por tempo suficiente, vai perceber que existem todas as combinações: usuários com alta e baixa pontuação, que fazem contribuições de qualidade boa e ruim. Sim, é possível ter alta pontuação mesmo com muitas contribuições ruins (afinal, se você conseguir um voto positivo e tomar 4 negativos, ainda sim terá um saldo positivo de pontos), basta participar ativamente por bastante tempo. E tem gente com pontuação não tão alta simplesmente porque participou pouco (mas esse pouco pode ter uma qualidade enorme, e no fim isso é mais importante que os pontos em si).

Mas na verdade os pontos têm utilidade sim: eles definem o que você pode fazer no site. Por exemplo, [para dar votos positivos, precisa ter no mínimo 15 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), [para comentar precisa de 50](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), para [votar negativo, 125](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), [fechar perguntas, 3000](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), e por aí vai ([veja aqui a lista completa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)).

E muitas dessas ações são importantes para manter a qualidade do conteúdo no site. Só para ficar em um exemplo, os votos são - ou pelo menos deveriam ser - [a segunda coisa mais importante do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/112052) (a primeira são as perguntas e respostas). Eles servem - ou pelo menos deveriam servir - para dar uma indicação da qualidade do conteúdo (não é perfeito, muita gente vota errado, tem resposta com gambiarras horrendas ou código que nem compila ganhando positivos, por exemplo, mas é o sistema que temos e deveríamos usar melhor). Então se zerar a pontuação, ninguém mais vai conseguir votar em nada. Hoje já está difícil as pessoas votarem (o pouco conteúdo bom que ainda aparece ganha pouquíssimos votos - [se comparado com antigamente, as pessoas estão votando menos](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1294799/quantidade-de-votos-por-mes#graph)), e se ninguém mais puder votar, como ficaria a classificação do conteúdo?

Todas as outras ações (fechar e reabrir perguntas, editar, sinalizar, acessar as filas de análise, etc) também são importantes para se manter a qualidade e o escopo do site. Se mais ninguém tiver acesso a estas funcionalidades, a qualidade - que já não anda boa - cai de vez (hoje já está difícil porque são poucos os que usam todas as funcionalidades - muitos já têm pontuação para tal mas não o fazem - e se ninguém mais puder fazer, aí degringola de vez).

> *"Ah, mas é fácil resolver, zera os pontos e deixa todo mundo fazer tudo."*

**Não.**

Essas limitações existem por um motivo.

Eu não acompanhei o site desde os primeiros dias, mas no início há um beta privado que não tem limitações (todo mundo pode fazer tudo), senão o site não conseguiria sequer começar. Em um site no início de sua vida, não tem muito jeito mesmo, mas depois que ele atinge determinado tamanho e entra em beta público, [passa a ter alguns limites (mais baixos que o atual)](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation). E conforme o site cresce, sai da fase beta e vira um [site oficial da rede Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), passa a ter os limites que tem atualmente.

E esses limites existem porque provavelmente perceberam que eles poderiam ser úteis. Por exemplo, exigir pontuação mínima para votar evita que as pessoas fiquem criando várias contas para votar nos amigos ou em si mesmo e inflar indevidamente a pontuação (ou votar negativo nos "desafetos"). Para fazer isso, a pessoa não só teria que criar várias contas, mas também conseguir a pontuação mínima em cada uma delas (e esse trabalho a mais já inibe bastante essa atitude).

Se hoje já temos distorções nos votos (respostas horríveis, com gambiarras, SQL Injection, explicam tudo errado, e mesmo assim ganham positivo; ou o contrário, respostas boas que ganham negativos de vingança, ou não ganham nenhum voto), imagine se retirarmos as restrições. Vai virar um Yahoo Respostas (onde a pessoa responde "não sei" e ganha votos).

[O mesmo vale para comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/817/112052): pode parecer uma limitação chata, mas evita muito *spam* e coisas questionáveis como "first!" e outras idiotices tão comuns em outros sites.

Enfim, as funcionalidades são liberadas de acordo com a pontuação porque a ideia é que, conforme a pessoa participa do site, ela vai entendendo melhor como ele funciona e tem mais maturidade e conhecimento de causa para usar as funcionalidades. Claro que não é um sistema perfeito (a pontuação por si só não garante que a pessoa vai usar corretamente, é só ver [os absurdos que acontecem nas filas de análise](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7606/112052)), mas ainda sim é melhor do que "liberar geral".

Se fosse para zerar os pontos, teríamos que usar outro critério para permitir que as pessoas usem as funcionalidades: como decidir quem pode votar, comentar, fechar perguntas, etc, sem gerar os problemas citados acima? É uma mudança tão fundamental no funcionamento do site que teria que ser muito bem pensado e discutido (mas se nem mudanças pequenas a SE está fazendo, imagine uma tão grande - provavelmente é mais fácil criar outro site).

---

Sobre a questão das pessoas editarem suas respostas para que elas apareçam na página principal e ganhem votos, bem, isso também não seria resolvido. As pessoas continuariam podendo editar suas postagens, e elas continuariam aparecendo na página principal. Na verdade dá para discutir se isso de fato é um problema relevante, pois [editar o conteúdo é parte fundamental do modelo do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing): a melhoria contínua das perguntas e respostas faz parte do processo de construir o repositório de conhecimento, e se um conteúdo bom foi melhorado, não vejo problemas em votar nele. **Se** isso de fato fosse um problema, acho até que poderia se agravar, pois com todos zerados, isso poderia incentivar ainda mais as pessoas a editarem para tentar ganhar votos.

---

Resumindo, zerar a pontuação não resolve nenhum dos problemas do site, e pode potencialmente criar outros. Não acho que seja uma ideia válida.

<sup>*E só para ser pedante, a [pontuação mínima que alguém pode ter é 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165703/401803). Mesmo se você levar 1 milhão de votos negativos, ela nunca ficará abaixo de 1. De qualquer forma, fazer todo mundo voltar para 1 não mudaria minha resposta :-)*</sup>

Comment: Boa resposta. Mas só deixar claro uma coisa. Nessa minha ideia surreal, a moderação continuaria e evitaria a "bagunça generalizada" nas perguntas e respostas. A única coisa que sairia seria a pontuação.

Comment: @GatodeSchrödinger Mas só a moderação não dá conta de tudo, a gente precisa que os demais usuários que já tem pontuação suficiente para acessar as funcionalidades de moderação as usem (fechar perguntas, editar, etc). Saindo a pontuação, precisaria de outro critério para permitir que os usuários façam isso (permitir para todos não seria uma solução, como eu já disse na resposta)

Comment: @GatodeSchrödinger Inclusive, a falta de participação da comunidade foi um dos motivos que [levaram um dos moderadores a se desmotivar de vez com o site](/a/8394/112052). Hoje já temos poucos usuários não-moderadores que ainda ajudam a manter o site mininamente organizado e os moderadores já estão sobrecarregados, se tirar a pontuação só sobrariam os moderadores e pioraria ainda mais a situação - Enfim, o papel de evitar a "bagunça generalizada" é de todos, infelizmente a maioria não está ajudando com isso

Comment: No começo de um site da rede há um beta privado onde os requisitos para tudo é ter 1 ponto. No beta público boa parte dos requisitos tem alguma pontuação necessária, mas é baixa, e quando o site gradua entra os pontos atuais.

Comment: @Maniero Não sabia disso. Atualizei a resposta, obrigado!